# Problem in creating view in mysql by subqueries

Tags: mysql, view, subquery

I want to create a view named `individual_info` which shows all information of individuals except their customer Ids and also lists how much balance each individual has in his/her account.

My Query is this:

```
Create VIEW individual_info AS
Select FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE, (Select MAX(AVAIL_BALANCE)
AS Total_Balance
FROM ACCOUNT
where CUST_ID < 10
GROUP BY CUST_ID) from INDIVIDUAL;
```

Now, this query will create the view, But when I want to see the information in that view by the following command:

```
select * from individual_info;
```

It will return an error:

```
ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

How to come out of this error?

Comment: Your subquery has a `GROUP BY CUST_ID`, which means that `MAX` is not aggregating. Remove the `GROUP BY` and it will return data.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us your table definitions, and to explain the purpose of your sub query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the subquery is grouped by cust_id and therefore returning the max of every cust_id<10 (?). What you need is a correlated query, I assume there is a cust_id in table individual, so your view should be something like this:

```
Create VIEW individual_info AS
Select FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE, (Select AVAIL_BALANCE
AS Total_Balance
FROM ACCOUNT as a
where a.CUST_ID = i.cust_id) 
from INDIVIDUAL as i
```

Note: you can also use a join instead of correlated query (it would be my preference):

```
CREATE VIEW individual_info AS
SELECT FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, BIRTH_DATE, coalesce(AVAIL_BALANCE,0)
AS Total_Balance
FROM INDIVIDUAL i
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT a
ON a.CUST_ID = i.cust_id
```

I included the coalesce in case there is no account record for some individuals, if that is the case these will show as 0 balance